# How to run a simple API request on Windows?

Tags: request, command

I'm a total beginner in this topic so please excuse me if I wrote something wrong. I want to run an simple API request which gives back information on carbon-dioxide levels in a specific country. I want to ask you on which software to use and how to make this code work.

Website with code: https://docs.co2signal.com/#introduction

My friend already successfully ran the code in Terminal on a Mac. He got the response with some CO2 data. When I tried it in Command Prompt on Win10, it didn't work. I tried also other programs like Git Bash or Postman. Still didn't work.

This is the original API request code:

curl 'https://api.co2signal.com/v1/latest?countryCode=DK'
  -H 'auth-token: myapitoken'

It requires an authentication token, which is: 2905e4afe4a7eb88 
Therefore, the right code should look like this:

curl 'https://api.co2signal.com/v1/latest?countryCode=DK'

-H 'auth-token: 2905e4afe4a7eb88'

Original website with code: https://docs.co2signal.com/#introduction

Expected result: A response from the server with CO2 levels data.

Actual results: In any program, there's a following error:
  "message": "No API key found in headers or querystring"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I got your question right, but I assume you want to access the API for some CO2 data from the Windows Command Line. You only got the MAC or Linux commands and want some way to translate this to be runnable on Windows.

You can use the Windows Powershell for this, e.g create a script `test.ps1`:

```bsh
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("auth-token", 'myapitoken')

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.co2signal.com/v1/latest?countryCode=DK' -Headers $headers

echo $response

PAUSE
```

The Invoke-RestMethod is part of PowerShell 3.0, cf. [here for the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-5.1).

Be aware that when you execute this snipet, the result is just printed to the console. The `PAUSE` command will hold the PowerShell window open after the request has finished.

The printed result I get looks like this:

```
_disclaimer : xyz
status      : ok
countryCode : DK
data        : @{fossilFuelPercentage=}
units       : @{carbonIntensity=gCO2eq/kWh}
```

Maybe you should also try another country code since there is no data for DK present.

Comment: Kryptur thanks for the response! Yes, I just want to access this API on Windows. I tried to follow your advice, but it didn't work. There's a chance I just didn't understand it well. Does it work on your computer?

Comment: Yes, it works on my Computer. I got the API result. What did you do to test the snippet?
1. Create a new file "test.ps1"
2. Edit it and paste the snippet inside, replace "myapitoken" with the actual token
3. Right click the file and choose "Execute with PowerShell" (or similar)